# Has anyone made a long-document smooth scroller / navigation bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, smooth-scrolling

I need to display a very long document which has numbered sections. The user could simply scroll through the document manually. As they do, the appropriate tab on the nav bar becomes highlighted. Clicking on a tab will, of course, cause the document to scroll directly to that spot.

I've been thinking that a vertical nav bar that's permanently visibile next to the document would be the best orientation.

Surely this has been done before, but I'm trying to find examples. And I'd really like to see someone doing this with jquery.

EDIt: http://pagescroller.com/ is pretty much exactly what I'm talking about. It's in beta, though. Any other options?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you want to check the jQuery Waypoints plugin:

http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

Open the above page, keep scrolling down, and watch the top-right menu.

Comment: Yes - I saw this too. I might be able to combine it with a scroll function to get both piece. E.g. http://www.devirtuoso.com/2011/11/smooth-scrolling-in-jquery/